# A set of prime factors of an integer in $\mathcal{O}_k$

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I've got a basic question from Thm 2 (ch.7, $\S2$) of Lang's Algebraic Number Theory.

Let $k$ be a number field and $A$ its adele group. Let $S_{\infty}$ be the set of Archimedean absolute values of $k$. Theorem says that $k+ A_{S_{\infty}}=A$ where $A_{S_{\infty}}$ is the subgroup of $S_{\infty}$-adeles.

During the proof, Lang states this:

Given $x\in A$, let $m$ be a rational integer such that $mx$ has integral components for all non-Archimedean $v$. Let $S$ be the set of primes $\mathfrak p$ of $\mathcal O_k$ such that $\mathfrak p \mid m$.

**Question:** what does $\mathfrak p \mid m$ mean here? $m$ is not necessarily prime, right?

He then uses this to show that $x-\alpha/m\in A_{S_{\infty}}$ where $\alpha\in \mathcal{O}_k$ satisfies $$mx\equiv\alpha \;\;(\text{mod }\mathfrak{p}^{\nu})$$ for all $\mathfrak p \in S$ and for some fixed large $\nu$.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: ${\frak p}\mid m$ means ${\frak p}\mid (m)$ as ideals where $(m)=m{\cal O}_k$, or equivalently $m\in\frak p$.

Comment: Ah, so $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_k$ which divides some prime factor of $m$?

Comment: Yes. Although that's a roundabout way to say it. Why say "it divides a prime factor of $m$" when you can just say "it divides $m$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the prime ideal $\frak p$ contains the ideal generated by $m$.